# Algorithm for distributed transaction involving database and file system on both client side and server side

Tags: c#, distributed-transactions

I am working on a .Net based, client/server versioning system which basically involves

At Client side:
   an embeded database
   file system

At server side:
   Sql server db
   file system

Everytime a new version is uploaded to the server from the client, the following steps happen:
1. Update the client side db with the new file metadata (new version#, timestamps, etc)
2. Send file to the server via HTTP, copy the file into server's file system
3. When file transfer finishes, update Sql server db with the new meta data

The whole process is treated as a transaction. The problem is, in case of failure, we have a hard time to roll back the transaction based on the different stage the error occurs.

My question is, what is the algorithm to handle this type of distributed commit? I've heard of 3-phase commit, is that a good suit for this scenario?

Thanks,

Comment: How are you handling the Commit / RollBack's Currently also don't you mean 2 Phase Commit..?

Comment: The database transactions are provided by the DBMS. For file system I just use C# code to copy/backup current or new versions. Thanks.

Comment: not a problem.. just wondering what your current process is .. what I pasted might help to shed some light on some idea(s)

Answer (score 0):

this is something that you can try but you will have to improve the example ..this is just an example on what you could do

```
using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection())
{
    using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            using (var scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
            {
                //when opening the connection, its' implicitly enlisted in the transaction scope
                conn1.Open();
                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn1);
                //set parameters
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn2.Open();
                SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn1);
                //set parameters
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //transaction commit/rolls back if an exception is thrown
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException ex)
        {
            //handle aborted transaction
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle other exceptions
        }
    }
}
```